# Can i create my Django project in C drive?

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I have only C drive and trying to create the django project in that Drive. Steps I followed:
Creating virtual environment which has python 3.6.4 and django 3.1.2

```
1. py -m pip install --user virtualenv
2. py -m venv env
3. .\env\Scripts\activate
```

(env) C:\Users\abhinavkumar\Desktop\Project>python

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

(env) C:\Users\abhinavkumar\Desktop\Project>pip freeze

```
asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1.2
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
```

Now creating Django project

```
1. (env) C:\Users\abhinav\Desktop
2. mkdir project
3. cd project
4. django-admin startproject projectname.
```

Issue i am facing is - I can't see the file projectname inside project directory(which i created in desktop).
On again trying to create the project with  projectname . it is showing as :
**CommandError: 'C:\Users\abhinavkumar\Desktop\Project\projectname' already exists**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to run these command in your terminal(where ever you want to be your project) and don't create any folder before these command these commands will automatically will create your project folder for you.

1. first running django-admin startproject command
2. then creating the conda environment through conda --name projectname python-version
3. then creating django app

Comment: Is it necessary to run using conda?

Comment: No it's not, you can use any environment.